# Why can't you have a limit point for an infinite number of zeroes to an analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm going through Ahlfors Complex Analysis, and in the proof to the formula for the number of zeroes of an analytic function, he states the following

$$n(\gamma,z_1)+n(\gamma,z_2)+\dots+n(\gamma,z_n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$$

> This is still true if $f(z)$ has infinitely many zeroes in $\Delta$.  It is clear that $\gamma$ is contained in a concentric disc $\Delta'$ smaller than $\Delta$.  Unless $f(z)$ is identically zero, a case which must obviously be excluded, it has only a finite number of zeroes in $\Delta'$.  This is an obvious consequence of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, for if there were infinitely many zeroes they would have an accumulation point in the closure of $\Delta'$, and this is impossible

Why is it impossible to have an accumulation point in the closure of $\Delta'$?  Is it because the closed curve would necessarily intersect it, so it would be impossible to have a closed curve which doesn't pass through a zero, and for there to be an accumulation point to the sequence of zeroes?  Couldn't the path just "slip through a gap" to get "through" the sequence?

Comment: Can you write that as an answer so I can give it a tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an analytic function's zeros have an accumulation point, the function is identically $0$. This is a consequence of what Wikipedia calls the "Identity Theorem":
[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)